# MySQL Workbench cannot connect to local server (OS X Yosemite 10.10)

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, osx-yosemite, mysql-5.6

MySQL workbench cannot connect to the local service. The service is running since I can use the mysql command to set the root password etc. I am new to OS X and MySQL.

Things I have tried:

- The service is running according to the prefs page
- In MySQL Workbench Rescan for local mysql instances (finds nothing)
- trying to connect from MySQL workbench using Standard TCP/IP and Local Socket Pipe don't find anything for (127.0.0.1)
- I created a my.cnf file by copying it from the sample configs, everything is commented out though, since I don't know what to put there.
- I went to this page but am not sure how to use these settings as they assume more knowledge than I have ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-connecting.html). I was able to find the mysql.sock but I don't know what to do with it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer on DBA Stack overflow see this question had an answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108522/mac-os-x-10-10-mysql-5-6-26-accessible-from-cli-but-not-port-3306 where one of the users says to check the file:

- /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist

In the file above you can see what port the server is listening on. In my case it was not the default 3306, but 3307. So when I changed the port Workbench connected and worked.